# Please someone give me the solution of this argument error

Tags: flutter, dart

As you can see below, I'm facing the problem that

> The argument type 'Object can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.

```dart
    double get totalSpending {
    return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + item['amount'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
            return Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: ChartBar(
                data['day'].toString(),
                data['amount'],
                totalSpending == 0.0
                    ? 0.0
                    : (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending,
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This is my first post on StackOverflow. Please help me out. The Problem is that The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.

Comment: Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: ChartBar(
                data['day'].toString(),
                data['amount'],
                totalSpending == 0.0
                    ? 0.0
                    : (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending,
              ),
            );          //The Problem is that The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.

Comment: Can you include more about `ChartBar`

Comment: Can you print `data['amount']` and `data['amount'].runtimeType` and tell the output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `item['amount']` is of type `Object`, so you should cast this to type `double` so you can add to `sum` which is also of type `double`.

change:

```dart
    double get totalSpending {
    return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + item['amount'];
    });
```

to this:

```dart
    double get totalSpending {
    return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + (item['amount'] as double);
    });
```

You might also need to change this:

```dart
              ...
              child: ChartBar(
                data['day'].toString(),
                data['amount'],
                totalSpending == 0.0
              ...
```

to this:

```dart
              ...
              child: ChartBar(
                data['day'].toString(), // or as String
                data['amount'] as double,
                totalSpending == 0.0
              ...
```